# Variable contador para cada fila que ingreso en tabla ASP Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

vengo con otro dilema, al momento de añadir una fila necesito que una variable de tipo contador almacene o vaya contado con cada interacción , debido a que en un futuro caso me permitirá ya que al el eliminar una fila de acuerdo a la posición no tendré mayor inconveniente, volviendo al tema cogí el siguiente código y lo metí en un for pero al momento de añadir se me añade 30 registros en vez de solo uno.

```
 function AnadirFilaPresup(event) {
    let hasError = false;
    var fila = 0;
    var a = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val();
    var b = $("#Nom_Pac").val();
    var c = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val();
    var d = $("#Rut_Pac").val();
    var e = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val();
    var f = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val();
    var g = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val();
    var h = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").val();
    var i = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").val();
    var j = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val();
    var k = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_SUB").val();
    if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val().length == 0) {
        console.log("ERROR: MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD");
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#Nom_Pac").val() == null || $("#Nom_Pac").val().length == 0) {
        console.log("ERROR: Nom_Pac");
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val().length == 0) {
        alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección del Profesional');
        console.log("ERROR: PRE_COD_ODON");
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").focus();
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#Rut_Pac").val() == null || $("#Rut_Pac").val().length == 0) {
        console.log("ERROR: Rut_Pac");
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val().length == 0) {
        alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección de la Dentadura');
        console.log("ERROR: PRE_DEN_PAC");
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").focus();
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val().length == 0) {
        alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección de la Pieza Dental');
        console.log("ERROR: PRE_PIE_DEN");
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").focus();
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val().length == 0) {
        alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección del Tratamiento');
        console.log("ERROR: PRE_TRA_PAC");
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").focus();
        hasError = true;
    }
    else {
        hasError = false;
        for (cont = 0; cont < 30; cont++) {
            fila++;
            if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val() != null && $("#Nom_Pac").val() != null && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val() != null
                && $("#Rut_Pac").val() != null && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val() != null && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val() != null
                && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val() != null) {
                var cadena = c.substring(5, 20);

                $("#tblTratamiento tbody").append("<tr><td>" + fila + "</td><td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + cadena + "</td><td>" + d + "</td><td>" + e +
                    "</td><td>" + f + "</td><td>" + g + "</td><td>" + h + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + j + "</td><td>" + k + "</td><td>" +
                    "<button type='button' id='btnDelete' class='btn bg-info btn-block text-light' onclick='BorrarFilaPresupuesto(event)'>ELIMINAR" +
                    "</button>" + "</td></tr > ");
                $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val('');
                $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val('');
                $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val('');
                $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").val('0');
                $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").val('0');
                $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val('0');
                $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_SUB").val('0');

                var total_col = 0;
                $("#tblTratamiento tbody").find("tr").each(function (i, el) {

                    //Voy incrementando las variables segun la fila ( .eq(0) representa la fila 1 )     
                    total_col += parseInt($(this).find("td").eq(10).text());
                });
                //Muestro el resultado en el th correspondiente a la columna
                $("#SUB_TOT_PRE").val(total_col);
                var tot1 = document.getElementById("SUB_TOT_PRE").value
                var pordscto = document.getElementById("POR_DSCTO_PRE").value
                var tot2 = document.getElementById("TOT_POR_DSCTO_PRE").value;
                var portarj = document.getElementById("POR_TAR_PRE").value
                var tot3 = document.getElementById("TOT_POR_TAR_PRE").value;
                tot2 = (tot1 * (pordscto / 100)).toFixed();
                tot3 = ((tot1 - tot2) * (portarj / 100)).toFixed();
                $("#TOT_POR_DSCTO_PRE").val(tot2);
                $("#TOT_POR_TAR_PRE").val(tot3);
                console.log(tot1, tot2, tot3);
                var suma = parseInt(tot1) - parseInt(tot2) + parseInt(tot3);
                $("#TOT_PAG_PRE").val(suma);
                $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").focus();
                hasError = false;
            }
            else {
                hasError = true;
                console.log("ERROR:! NO SE INGRESA NINGUNA FILA");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda y guía , ya que la solución debería ser sencilla pero me estoy haciendo bolas con algo tan pequeño.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de una pequeña ayuda logre conseguir la respuesta que como buen colega deja a continuación, mi primer error era en la declaración de la variable al colocarla dentro del método por cada interacción se seteaba en 1, al colocarla como variable global no ocurre esto, si existe otro método que realice lo mismo me pueden indicar para saber e implementar.

```
   var fila_ana_pre = 1;

function AnadirFilaPresup(event) {
    let hasError = false;
    var a = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val();
    var b = $("#Nom_Pac").val();
    var c = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val();
    var d = $("#Rut_Pac").val();
    var e = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val();
    var f = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val();
    var g = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val();
    var h = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").val();
    var i = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").val();
    var j = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val();
    var k = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_SUB").val();
    if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val().length == 0) {
        console.log("ERROR: MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD");
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#Nom_Pac").val() == null || $("#Nom_Pac").val().length == 0) {
        console.log("ERROR: Nom_Pac");
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val().length == 0) {
        alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección del Profesional');
        console.log("ERROR: PRE_COD_ODON");
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").focus();
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#Rut_Pac").val() == null || $("#Rut_Pac").val().length == 0) {
        console.log("ERROR: Rut_Pac");
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val().length == 0) {
        alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección de la Dentadura');
        console.log("ERROR: PRE_DEN_PAC");
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").focus();
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val().length == 0) {
        alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección de la Pieza Dental');
        console.log("ERROR: PRE_PIE_DEN");
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").focus();
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val() == null || $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val().length == 0) {
        alert('Clínica Equilibrium, Realiza la Selección del Tratamiento');
        console.log("ERROR: PRE_TRA_PAC");
        $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").focus();
        hasError = true;
    }
    else {
        hasError = false;
        if ($("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val() != null && $("#Nom_Pac").val() != null && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val() != null
            && $("#Rut_Pac").val() != null && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val() != null && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val() != null
            && $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val() != null) {
            var cadena = c.substring(5, 20);
            $("#tblTratamiento tbody").append("<tr><td>" + fila_ana_pre + "</td><td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + cadena + "</td><td>" + d + "</td><td>" + e +
                "</td><td>" + f + "</td><td>" + g + "</td><td>" + h + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + j + "</td><td>" + k + "</td><td>" +
                "<button type='button' id='btnDelete' class='btn bg-info btn-block text-light' onclick='BorrarFilaPresupuesto(event)'>ELIMINAR" +
                "</button>" + "</td></tr > ");
            fila_ana_pre++;
            console.log(($("table#tblTratamiento tr:last").index() + 1));
            $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val('');
            $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val('');
            $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val('');
            $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").val('0');
            $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").val('0');
            $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val('0');
            $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_SUB").val('0');

            var total_col = 0;
            $("#tblTratamiento tbody").find("tr").each(function (i, el) {

                //Voy incrementando las variables segun la fila ( .eq(0) representa la fila 1 )     
                total_col += parseInt($(this).find("td").eq(10).text());
            });
            //Muestro el resultado en el th correspondiente a la columna
            $("#SUB_TOT_PRE").val(total_col);
            var tot1 = document.getElementById("SUB_TOT_PRE").value
            var pordscto = document.getElementById("POR_DSCTO_PRE").value
            var tot2 = document.getElementById("TOT_POR_DSCTO_PRE").value;
            var portarj = document.getElementById("POR_TAR_PRE").value
            var tot3 = document.getElementById("TOT_POR_TAR_PRE").value;
            tot2 = (tot1 * (pordscto / 100)).toFixed();
            tot3 = ((tot1 - tot2) * (portarj / 100)).toFixed();
            $("#TOT_POR_DSCTO_PRE").val(tot2);
            $("#TOT_POR_TAR_PRE").val(tot3);
            console.log(tot1, tot2, tot3);
            var suma = parseInt(tot1) - parseInt(tot2) + parseInt(tot3);
            $("#TOT_PAG_PRE").val(suma);
            $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").focus();
         
            hasError = false;
        }
        else {
            hasError = true;
            console.log("ERROR:! NO SE INGRESA NINGUNA FILA");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```